# How to identify page has been loaded in LWC component?

Tags: lightning-web-components, connected-callback

I have a lwc component and it is using pubsub. When page is getting loaded pubsub is firing again and again. And hence increasing the page load time. Is there any way we can prevent pubsub to fire on first time page load? We are using connectedCallback() to call our logic and pubsubs. So we are thinking if we can identify page load is complete and push all pubsubs in this method. Since we do not need pubsubs on initial page loads. Is there any method provided by salesforce/javascript such documentComplete, which can be used to identify load complete.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read about [ask] and take the [tour]. This question appears to be in [X-Y](https://xyproblem.info/) format. If you could provide some code we could review, we might be able to offer you a better solution; pubsub should not significantly increase load time if done correctly. You can [edit] your question to include the relevant code and more context.